# How to Overlay Charts of Different Dates on TradingView?

Tags: charts, tradingview-api

I want to create a chart similar to the one below. I want to overlay S&P500 data from 2008 with S&P500 data of 2022 to compare their charts and see how this current bear market correlates with the one from 2008. How do I do this in TradingView? I've tried for an hour and haven't figured it out.

[image]